# Visual Studio Code, how to change background of a specific

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to change the background of a specific scope (code.block) in VSCode as I do with sublime. [sublimetext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOMHQ.png)
Block comment has different background, hence it is easier to notice.

Although I made necessary modifications to relevant json file, and foreground colors displayed correctly, backgroundcolor is always overriden by the background of editor. the background field (ff0000 marked with red) changes correctly but the displayed background field (1d1a18 marked with green) is the background of the editor.
[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBk2B.png)

I use meterial dark soda theme.
Anyone knows how to disable this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Here's the issue tracking: [#3429](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3429).